# Trigger AWS lambda from AWS AURORA after modification to the table

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-aurora

What are the points that need to concern when integrating AWS lambda and AWS aurora..? Will there be any performance degradations ..? Can someone please share any experience ..?

Answer (score 1):

SO is more for code syntax, bugs, behaviors than general advice. The question subject regards rds event notification and you ask in description about performance, general concerns about integration of lambda and aurora. Try [this rds tutorial](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/vpc-rds.html) it is for RDS in general but should work very similar to aurora.